# How can I iteratively write text data to new files based on the first character of each line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text

I receive many text files formatted like this:

```
100000054896524Textext
30000680235498065464065     texttext
50005065321465406546406     16227322
7000056432586846403546854065354096
50046540632146540665406     16268431
7000066543241564786413468464163156
30065406346840654065486     TEXTETXT
```

I need to write the contents of these files to new files based on the first character of these lines, so that I have n number of files per first character. For the data above I would have four new files:

`file1.txt`:

```
100000054896524Textext
```

`file3.txt`:

```
30000680235498065464065     texttext
30065406346840654065486     TEXTETXT
```

`file5.txt`:

```
50005065321465406546406     16227322
50046540632146540665406     16268431
```

and `file7.txt`:

```
7000056432586846403546854065354096
7000066543241564786413468464163156
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I've tried the following:

```
with open('test_file.txt','r') as file_handle:
    file_content = file_handle.read()

with open('file1.txt', 'w') as file_handle:
    for line in file_content:
        if line[0] == '1':
            file_handle.write(line+'\n')

with open('file3.txt', 'w') as file_handle:
    for line in file_content:
        if line[0] == '3':
            file_handle.write(line+'\n')
```

and so on for 5 and 7 but this just gets me files with a bunch of 1s and 3s without the data...

What is it that I don't understand? Thank you.

Comment: Have you verified that the value of `line` is as you expect?

Comment: In your own words, when you do `file_content = file_handle.read()`, what do you expect to be the *type* of `file_content` as a result? What do you, therefore, expect to happen when iterating like `for line in file_content:`?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.  In many cases, doing this basic diagnosis will show you where the problem lies, and you won't need Stack Overflow at all.  You haven't validated *any* of your code; doing so will pinpoint each of the problems in turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than calling `open` individually for each file, it would be cleaner to use a dictionary. Here's a working example:

```py
output = {}

with open('testfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        start_char = line[0]
        if start_char not in output:
            output[start_char] = []
        output[start_char].append(line)

for start_char in output.keys():
    with open('file{}.txt'.format(start_char), 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(output[start_char])
```

Comment: This doesn't explain what the problem was in the original code.

Answer (score 3):

Use `readlines()` instead of `read()` (line 2)

Using `file_handle.read()` instead of `file_handle.readlines()` will return a string, so using `file_handle.read()` will iterate char by char.

Using `readlines()` will iterate line by line because that function will return a list.

Comment: Good catch! Now also explain _why_ they need to use `readlines()` instead of `read()` in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

`read` reads the file as a single string. When you iterate, you are iterating character by character, not line by line. You could use `file_content = file_handle.readlines()` so that you iterate lines not characters.

And instead of duplicating code for each file, setup a cache and let your script create the files dynamically.

```
# will hold open file objects for "file0.txt", ..., "file9.txt"
# as needed
file_cache = [None] * 10

try:
    with open('test_file.txt') as file_handle:
        for line in file_handle:
            num = int(line[0])
            if file_cache[num] is None:
                file_cache[num] = open(f"file{num}.txt", "w")
            file_cache[num].write(line)
# todo: May want to catch exceptions and delete all files on fail
# except:...
finally:
    for fp in file_cache:
        if fp:
            fp.close()
```

Answer (score -2):

You could open the right files dynamically as needed as you read your input file:

```py
open_files = {}

with open('test_file.txt','r') as file_handle:
    for line in file_handle:
        digit = line[0]
        fname = f'file{digit}.txt'

        if fname in open_files:
           write_file = open_files[fname]
        else:
           open_files[fname] = open(fname, 'w')
           write_file = open_files[fname]

        write_file.write(line)

    for write_file in open_files.values():
        write_file.close()
```